# How can I avoid duplicate data in Firebase / Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a web page, but when entering the same ID an error should come out, but I have not been able to do it.

```js
 function save () {
    if (validate  = true) {
        console.log("exists!")
    }else {
        
    var imei = document.getElementById('imei').value;
    var marca = document.getElementById('marca').value;
    var referencia = document.getElementById('referencia').value;
    var precio = document.getElementById('precio').value;

    db.collection("phone").add({
        Imei: imei,
        Marca: marca,
        Referencia: referencia,
        Precio: precio
    })
        .then(function (docRef) {
            document.getElementById('imei').value = '';
            document.getElementById('marca').value = '';
            document.getElementById('referencia').value = '';
            document.getElementById('precio').value = '';
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            window.alert("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    }
}save();

function validate () {
    firebase.database().ref(`phone/${Imei}/imei`).once("value", snapshot => 
    { const imei = snapshot.val(); 
        if (imei){ 
            console.log("user exists!"); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

If you can tell me where I have the error, or the best solution I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems with your code:

1. You're building the path with `phone/${Imei}/imei`, but your variable name is spelled `imei` (and not `Imei`). Case matter in JavaScript, as it does in most programming languages, so I recommend paying close attention to spelling and case.
2. You're not calling `validate()` anywhere, which means your check doesn't run.
3. You're not returning anything from `validate()`. And since what you want to return comes from the database in an asynchronous call, you can only return it with a promise or `async` / `await`. This aslome could warrant its own answer, so I recommend you study [Firebase, retrieving data asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302577/firebase-retrieving-data-asynchronously/39303194#39303194), [How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function) and [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)
4. You really should use a transaction to ensure no-one may claim the IMEI between the read and write operation in your code.
5. If the IMEI value should be unique, it is better to use that as the **key** instead of as a property value. Read more on that here:

Combining all these, a better implementation might look something like:

```
function save () {
    var imei = document.getElementById('imei').value;
    var marca = document.getElementById('marca').value;
    var referencia = document.getElementById('referencia').value;
    var precio = document.getElementById('precio').value;

    var imeiDocRef = db.collection("phone").doc(imei);

    db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
        // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
        return transaction.get(imeiDocRef).then(function(imeiDoc) {
            if (imeiDoc.exists) {
                throw `IMEI '${imei}' already exist!`;
            }

            transaction.set(imeiDocRef, { 
                Imei: imei,
                Marca: marca,
                Referencia: referencia,
                Precio: precio
            });
        });
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
        document.getElementById('imei').value = '';
        document.getElementById('marca').value = '';
        document.getElementById('referencia').value = '';
        document.getElementById('precio').value = '';
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
    });
}
```